# How to get consumer secret key for Google+

Tags: android, gmail-api

I am trying to get Consumer Secret key for Android in Google+ 
But haven't find any key yet 
I downloaded the JSON file but still there is no sign of Consumer secret key 
can anybody help me?

Comment: This may help : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: I need to get consumer secret key when I am creating client ID 
That's what I need 
But I am not finding it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Consumer Secret key is for the older version of OAuth or for a different authentication protocol, because in Google's OAuth 2.0 there no such thing (unless you meant clientSecret). For authenticating G+ on Android check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started). All you should need is the SHA-1 fingerprint to create your clientID. Then with the `GoogleApiClient`, you can authenticate those credentials and access the API.

Comment: Actually I am using SocialAuth and SocialAuth requires Consumer secret key
Can I use anything else instead of Consumer Secret key?

Comment: It seems rather than creating a clientID for Installed Application you create one for a Web Application (despite it being on Android). 
https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/wiki/GooglePlus

I think the clientSecret is what you want.

Comment: What should I put in Authorized Javascript origin and Authorized redirected URI?

Comment: Typically, you put your domain and a callback url. But since if this is android, you may not have that. The steps linked suggest to take a look at custom-ui example, which I believe you can find here:
https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android/tree/master/custom-ui

Comment: I din't understand what I have to do with this github project 
can I put any random url in those two fields ?